# Seaborn: change the order of x lab

Tags: seaborn

I tried this:

```
sns.countplot(x=df["EDAD"]
              , hue=df["SEXO"])
```

and i get this [This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFG7r.png)

i want the order below: (which is the order of the dataset)
18-30 años
31-45 años
46-65 años
66 en adelante

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom `order` to [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

```
sns.countplot(x=df["EDAD"], hue=df["SEXO"],
              order=['18-30 años', '31-45 años', '46-65 años', '66 años o más'])
```

Example output:

[image]